# How many GB do Black Ops 2 and MW3 take up?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

How much space does it take for Black Ops 2 on PS3? and How much does Modern Warfare 3 take up?

i do not own any of these games.

Comment: Doesn't it tell you when you try to install it? There's not a mandatory install for either game, both say < 100 mb required hdd space on the box.

Comment: If you dont own these games why ask the question

Comment: @stizzle84 - Probably because it was a purchasing decision of whether to buy the new games

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BO 2 has an optional install for textures, which takes 1.8GB. The game requires ~10MB for save files. DLC is extra.

MW3 has a 50MB requirement. No additional install. DLC is extra.

Answer (score 0):

PS3 does not install the entire game disc like 360 so install sizes are considerably smaller than full game installs (PSN version, for example).

According to [this](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-black-ops-2-face-off) BOII PS3 install size is only 1.8GB.

I cannot find any data on MW3 install.

Answer (score -3):

Black ops 2 is 1.8 GB and 10 MB for the save file, excluding the space for the dlc. Modern Warfare 3 is 50 MB for the save file.

Comment: So you copied the accepted answer and reanswered it more than half a year later?